# Identify input maps corresponding to control system ($A,B$), where $B = \delta_0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, semigroups-of-operators

The text I'm struggling with comes from "Observation and Control for Operator Semigroups" by Tucsnak and Weiss, page 119.
Take $X = L^2(0,\infty)$ and let $X_{-1}$ be the dual of the Sobolev space $H^1(0,\infty)$ with respect to the pivot space $X$. Let $(A,B)$ be a control system with $A = -\frac{d}{dx}$ with $D(A) = H^1_0(0,\infty)$ (space of those functions in $\phi \in H^1(0,\infty)$ for which $\gamma_0(\phi) = 0$), it generates the right shift semigroup on $X$, which can be extended to a semigroup on $X_{-1}$ denoted by $T_{-1}$. In the book, it is written that the space $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C},X_{-1})$ can be identified with $X_{-1}$. Then, authors define $\delta_a$, an element of $X_{-1}$, by $\delta_a(\phi) = \phi(a)$ for $\phi \in H^1_0(0,\infty)$. The control operator in this problem is $B = \delta_0$ and I don't understand where does this identification between $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C},X_{-1})$ and $X_{-1}$ came from, we need it, because $B$ should be in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C},X_{-1})$.

Another thing is, we need to specify input maps, that is $\Phi_{\tau}u = \int_0^{\tau} T_{-1}(\tau - \sigma)Bu(\sigma)\ d\sigma$. They write, it is not difficult to check that
\begin{equation}
(\Phi_{\tau}u)(x) = \begin{cases}
u(t - x)\qquad & \text{for } x \in [0,t],\\
0\qquad & \text{for } x \geq t. 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I don't seee where this came from, possibly because I don't understand the way $\delta_0$ turns into $B$, an element of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C},X_{-1})$.